# pyspark: get size of the second element of a groupby on rdd

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd which I create from an input like the following:

```
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 3
```

I do a groupBy like the following:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.groupBy(lambda x: x[0])
```

Now rdd2 would be something like:

```
[(0,[1,2]),(1,[2,3])]
```

MY questions is, how can I get the size of that list associated with each element?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapValues` and `len`:

```
rdd2.mapValues(list).mapValues(len)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need a groupBy when you have countByKey()

```
    rdd = sc.parallelize(inputData)
    rdd.countByKey()
```

Output will be a dictionary:

> defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {0: 2, 1: 2})